# R join data.frames or data.tables using %like% or contains

Tags: r, data.table

In SQL you can join tables like this:

`...on table1.long_id like '%'+table2.short_id+'%'`

where the long_id is a long string that may or may not contain the short_id and `%` is a wildcard.

Is there a way to join like this in **R**, preferably in **data.table**? Something like this:

`table1[table2, on = .(long_id %like% short_id)]`

I thought it may be possible as a part of non-equi joins but couldn't figure out how to do it. Thanks!

EDIT

I've added a reproducible example below.

With the two data tables below, I'd like to join on longid contains shortid.

```
    t1<- data.table(longid=c("5-6-7", "6-4-6", "4-1-5", "4-2-9", "2-8-6"))
    t2<- data.table(shortid=c("1", "2", "3"))
```

I'd like the result to be like this

```
    result <- data.table(shortid=c("1", "2", "2"), longid=c("4-1-5", "4-2-9", 
    "2-8-6"))
```

Comment: It's more likely that you will get a good, and prompt,  answer if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question.

Comment: There are various related open issues, like https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1431

Comment: You may want to just use the `sqldf` package and write the actual SQL

Comment: I've added a reproducible example--thanks for the tip, Eric. I've thought about the sqldf package, that may be my best bet it sounds like.

Comment: I would love this to be a feature in data.table at some point. This is my solution in sqldf: sqldf("select t2.*, t1.* from t1 join t2 on t1.longid like '%'||t2.shortid||'%'")

Answer (score 1):

Your dataframes:

```
t1<- data.table(longid=c("5-6-7", "6-4-6", "4-1-5", "4-2-9", "2-8-6"))
t2<- data.table(shortid=c("1", "2", "3"))
```

With grepl I find the id cointained

```
TF<-sapply(as.character(t2$shortid),grepl,x=as.character(t1$longid)) #Like operation using grepl
```

Here I find the match

```
max1<-apply(TF,1,function(x) which(x==1)) #Find match in t1
max2<-apply(t(TF),1,function(x) which(x==1)) #Find match in t2
```

Combining the output

```
    out<-cbind(t1[rep(seq_len(nrow(t1)), unlist(lapply(max1,length))),],t2[rep(seq_len(nrow(t2)), unlist(lapply(max2,length))),]) #bind t1 and t2 matches
out
   longid shortid
1:  4-1-5       1
2:  4-2-9       2
3:  2-8-6       2
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still trying to figure out exactly what's happening here. My first thought is it's a bit more verbose than I'd like. Also, it is breaking for me on the the "out" step.

Comment: Code changed according to your example, added some comments. If you have any questions let me know.

Comment: That is working for me, thank you for the base R solution. However, I do prefer the sqldf option just because it's much simpler.

Comment: Yes, sqldf is the right solution. I was curious to find a solution R base based so a go deeper in the coding.